# MySQL - any way to join to table using a mask?

Tags: mysql

The column I want to join my 2 tables on conceptually has the same meaning but the wording may be different. I wonder if there is any way to match them based on a few characters of a word.

Example:
table 1 has HAZMAT and  table 2 has ADDITIONAL HAZARDOUS. Let's say I want to use table 1 LEFT(column, 3) to select the HAZ part and match it to cells that contain this part.

Comment: You can join tables using any conditions, it's just most (out of all possible conditions) don't make sense, and others (like the one you are suggesting) an be quite poor performing. You'd want something like `ON t2.some_column LIKE CONCAT('%', LEFT(t1.column, 3), '%')`... but again, this is likely to have very poor performance... and would also join t1 entries with things like "DOUBLE", "ION", "ARDUOUS", "DITTO", "ADDITIVE", etc... with t2 entries with "ADDITIONAL HAZARDOUS".

Comment: I agree with you but I can't think of anything else. Maybe creating a temporary table and assign similar wording to the same number would be better? In my example, HAZMAT and ADDITIONAL HAZARDOUS are basically the same thing, it's just that they are worded differently.

Comment: I have to question why you would be joining two tables with no directly relatable data. Even if `HAZMAT` and `ADDITIONAL HAZARDOUS` did not have other words generating "false positive" matches, you still have the problem of every HAZMAT being matched with every ADDITIONAL HAZARDOUS....meaning 6 of the former and 7 of the latter yield 42 result rows.

Comment: @alexb Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.